# Can't remove crankset! bad tool?

Tags: crankset, tools

I would like to remove the crankset on this bike but my crankset remover tool can't fit in because the "screw" inside of the crankset remover is hanging, even when I screw it to the minimum. Is it normal?

Plus, I think the "screw" inside of the crankset is also hanging a lot compared to other bikes I saw, but I may be wrong here...

Do you have any advice to remove the crankset? I was thinking of buying a 3-jaw puller...

[image]

[image]
[image]

Comment: Whilst it's always fair to blame the tool, does it have a little allen fitting in the very tip? look down the tool from the end, if you can remove the tip with a  little allen key it would make it shorter and it may then fit in the space

Comment: @Swifty the extra tip is held on with a magnet on mine. Unless you drive the tip far enough out to see its base, you wouldn't be able to take it off, or even know it was removable. The purpose is to change the width - wide for octalink, narrow for square taper.

Comment: thanks, Swifty! good comment but unfortunately, there is no way to remove a part of the tool to make it fit...

Comment: Oh no, well that does seem like a bit of bad luck between the older style spindle and presumably a modern spec puller. @ChrisH interesting that one should be magnetic, I haven't come across that yet

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Remove the bolt from the bottom bracket. On the crank remover, unwind the center bolt until it is all the way out - this is super important. Screw the crank puller onto the crank until it stops, tighten firmly, not too much. Make sure it is threaded in all the way and not been stopped by the pullers center bolt which should still be loose. Wind the crank puller center bolt in to pull the crank.

Leaving the center bolt extended like yours is can lead to not enough thread engagement when you install the crank puller, which can result in stripped threads on the crank - then you are in trouble.

Good video here from Park Tool...

Comment: Thank you very much mattnz! I have done this operation a few times on different bike but never face this issue. BUT I think I found the issue, and this is my crankset tool remover, here is a video with similar set up (a "screw" hanging out of the BB). My tool is already set to the minimum limit on my pictures and doesn't allow me to use it for this type of bike. https://www.youtube.com/watch?app=desktop&v=63HX-ioPsHw&ab_channel=Virgoantonio